# Inserting new element on dynamic array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

I have a class representing an array, holding pointers to my other class objects.

```
#include "Edge.h"  
class Array
{
private:
    Edge** _headPtr;    
    int arraySize;      

public:
    Array(int);
    void pushBack(Edge*);
    // other functions...
};

Array::Array(int arraySize)
{
    this->arraySize = arraySize;
    this->_headPtr = new Edge*[arraySize];
}
```

Program always returns memory allocation errors after calling

```
// inserts an element on the end of the array
void Array::pushBack(Edge* element)
{
    if (arraySize == 0) {
        _headPtr = new Edge*[1];
        _headPtr[0] = element;
        arraySize++;
    }
    else {
        Edge** _tempPtr = new Edge*[arraySize + 1]; // crashing here            
        memcpy(_tempPtr, _headPtr, arraySize * sizeof(Edge*));

        //for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) delete _headPtr[i];
        delete[] _headPtr;

        _tempPtr[arraySize] = element;
        _headPtr = _tempPtr;
        arraySize++;
    }
}
```

I have commented out the `for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) delete _headPtr[i];`
part because it was causing `_free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);` error.

From what I've found in other questions here I guess there must be a flaw in my understanding of dynamic array of pointers to class objects, but after spending much time trying to fix this I've run out of ideas.
The general idea of my program is to perform time efficiency measurements for some graph algorithms, this being part of Prim's algorithm implementation.
Call stack leading to this situation looks like this:

```
    BinaryHeap queue = BinaryHeap();
    queue.addNewElement(new Edge(v, v2, edgeWeight));
    which looks like this
    void BinaryHeap::addNewElement(Edge* element)
    {
        heapElements->pushBack(element);
        heapFix_UP(heapElements->getSize()-1);
    }
    And finally pushBack method.
```

`heapElements` is `Array* heapElements` inside the BinaryHeap class, initialized with
 `heapElements = new Array();` in BinaryHeap constructor.
Edge is a very simple class holding only three integer values.
Please do not suggest using std::vector, the whole idea is not to use STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution. All of the code above works good, the bug was in a completely different place in my code.
What was so wrong that it was causing the whole program to crash many lines later?
This:

```
int** graphMatrix;
graphMatrix = new int*[vertex];
for (i = 0; i < edges; i++) graphMatrix[i] = new int[edges];
```

So simple, yet so harmful.
It is a part of my incidence matrix implementation. Now the reason for all crashes is pretty obvious - trying to write/read unallocated memory and causing heap corruptions.